# Cmake FindBoost error-POP without matching PUSH

Tags: c++, c, boost, cmake, lightgbm

I am trying to install LightGBM-gpu on Centos. It seems boost 1.56 can be find, but this error occurred.I google it all day but can not solve it.

**Here is the Message**

```
$ cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include/ ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "3.1")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "3.1")
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_1_2 - found
-- Found OpenCL: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libOpenCL.so (found version "1.2")
-- OpenCL include directory: /usr/local/cuda/include
Boost 1.56.0 found.
Found Boost components:
filesystem;system
CMake Error in /usr/local/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:
cmake_policy POP without matching PUSH
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:144 (find_package)

-- Performing Test MM_PREFETCH
-- Performing Test MM_PREFETCH - Success
-- Using _mm_prefetch
-- Performing Test MM_MALLOC
-- Performing Test MM_MALLOC - Success
-- Using _mm_malloc
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/rd/LightGBM/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/rd/LightGBM/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: Looks like [that issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17309). Just update CMake (not Boost!) to any newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was cross-posted to the LightGBM issues page as [microsoft/LightGBM#3613](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3613). The issue was solved there.

Updating `CMake` to at least version 3.14 fixes this issue.